# How to export images from Photoshop to android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

suppose I have an image view in my layout 100 dp by 100 dp ..

should the image I export from photoshop be 100 px by px or what?

Comment: You should output it in multiple sizes. [Read these docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) which show you best how to support a variety of screen sizes.

Comment: What size will the image be shown on the screen? Will it be a variable/percentage width? And what types of screens?

Comment: I know some of the basic stuff, what confuses me though is ..
exporting an image from photoshop asks for specifying both the width and height in pixels and the resolution in pixels per inch also..

Answer (score 1):

Generally, your source image (from photoshop) should be of a higher resolution than what would be displayed in Android.  For a average icon size of 48dp by 48dp, a source image of 100px by 100px is good.

Assuming you are using Android Studio (AS), it can create the necessary image sizes from the higher resolution image.  You do this in AS by right clicking on the project res folder, New, Image Asset.  This gives you the Image Asset screen.  Choose Icon Type = Launcher Icons (Legacy only), Asset Type = Image, Path = (location of your image), Name = (your icon name, e.g. ic_test), Scaling = Shrink to Fit, Shape = None (especially if your image has transparent colors) and then AS will create the necessary image sizes placing these in the right project resource directories.

Access the image from your code with R.mipmap.ic_test, e.g, button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_test).  Android will take care of which image resolution / size to use based on the device.

Comment: Thanks! Saved my life!

But I'm still wondering is there a way to make vector drawables from PSDs that are a little complicated (with shadow effects for example)...